# Probability that a triangle inscribed in an ellipse contains one of its foci

Tags: probability, conic-sections, geometric-probability

Three points are chosen at random on the border of an ellipse. Those three points makes a triangle. Since ellipse has two focus points, question here is what is the probability of that triangle to contain one of those foci. I've noticed that when we take two points and draw a line through one of focus points, the third point should be in the arc where this two points lines contains to form a triangle in order to contain that focus point, then I tried to go on from angle of that two lines intersection at the focus point but since arclength varies due to change of that angle, i couldn't figure out how should I go on.

Comment: Can you solve the problem for a circle?

Comment: yes you can see the solutions in the following link [link]https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/ThreeRandomPointsOnCircle.shtml

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I'm almost sure that solving the problem for a circle will not help for the general case. The result will depend on the eccentricity $e$ of the ellipse, with a probability tending to $0$ when $e \to 1$.

Comment: Are your points chosen inside or on the border of the ellipse ?

Comment: on the border of the ellipse

Comment: Have you done numerical simulations ?

Comment: no I haven't because I don't know how I can do it

Comment: You need to specify the distribution of the points. E.g. they could be equidistributed according to the arc length, or the angle could be uniformly distributed.